# cannot add my data to mysql using tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, exception, tkinter

i'm adding data into mysql using tkinter
so when i add my 1st student  it  shows added successfully 
but when i add my 2nd  student it shows roll number exist even when i change roll number (without closing my program)

but if i close my program and add again it again add 1st student and shows roll umber already exist in 2nd student

```
def add_data():
    name=e1.get()
    rol=e2.get()
    phn=e3.get()
    mth=e4.get()
    eng=e5.get()
    sci=e6.get()

    try:
        if(rad.get()==1):
            cursor.execute('insert into first_year( name,roll_number,phn_no,maths,english,science) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',(name, rol, phn, mth, eng, sci))
        elif(rad.get()==2):
            cursor.execute('insert into second_year( name,roll_number,phn_no,maths,english,science) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',(name, rol, phn, mth, eng, sci))

        con.commit()
        con.close()
        confimation.config(text="added succesfully")
        e1.delete(0, END)
        e2.delete(0, END)
        e3.delete(0, END)
        e4.delete(0, END)
        e5.delete(0, END)
        e6.delete(0, END)
    except:
        confimation.config(text="roll number exist")

btn=Button(f,text="ADD",command=add_data)
btn.place(x=600,y=350,height=90,width=90)
```

[image: my image when im trying to add 2nd student data]

[image: my table image]

[image: error after changing my exception]

[image: error after removing try and except]

Comment: Say `except Exception as e:    print(e)` and let us know what it is

Comment: @CoolCloud Your correct I edited my answer so he can format his code this way instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what the error is now, You are closing your connection then trying to re-use the same cursor you had defined before. Try removing "con.close()" from your try loop and see if this works. Global cursors can fail over larger datasets but this should fix your issue.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222454/discussion-on-answer-by-oddity-cannot-add-my-data-to-mysql-using-tkinter).